# Proof of Wikipedia formula about Ricci curvature

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, tensors, curvature

In the [Wikipedia article on Ricci curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature#Direct_geometric_meaning) there is a formula, the third of the paragraph "Direct geometric meaning", that reads:
$$
d\mu_g = \Big[ 1 - \frac{1}{6}R_{jk}x^jx^k+ O(|x|^3) \Big] d\mu_{{\rm Euclidean}}\,.
$$

The article says that this is computed from:
$$
g_{ij} = \delta_{ij} - \frac{1}{3}R_{ikj\ell}x^kx^\ell + O(|x|^3)\,,
$$

which is easily found (e.g. in John Lee, Riemannian Manifolds). But how does one go from the latter to the former? And, more important, is there a text in which this is done, possibly with some context?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have found a trick! For a positive definite matrix $M$ close enough to the identity (as in our case), we have:
$$
\log(\det M) = \mbox{Tr}(\log M)\;.
$$

In my case:
$$
\sqrt{g} = \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})}=\exp\bigg(\dfrac{1}{2}\mbox{Tr}(\log(g_{ij}))\bigg) \approx 1 +\dfrac{1}{2}\mbox{Tr}\bigg(-\dfrac{1}{3} R_{ikjl}\,x^kx^l\bigg)\;.
$$

All the terms missing would be $O(x^3)$ or higher, so we just get:
$$
1 -\dfrac{1}{6} \sum_i R_{ikil}\,x^kx^l=1 -\dfrac{1}{6} R_{kl}\,x^kx^l\;.
$$

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that since the covariant volume $dV=\sqrt{-g} d^n x$, where $g=|g_{ij}|$ is the determinant of the metric, is conserved we have that:
$$\sqrt{-g} dV_g=dV_{Euclidian}$$
since the Euclidean metric is $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$ and its determinant is one.

Using the expansion
$$g_{ij} = \delta_{ij} - \frac{1}{3}R_{ikj\ell}x^kx^\ell + O(|x|^3)\,,$$ to compute $\sqrt{-g}$ and rearranging should give the desired result.

Cheers

Comment: Yes, it's a determinant. But a very complicated one. That's why I would like to see the calculation done somewhere, or at least some tricks to simplify the math...